# CANoe use 2 LDF

Tags: capl, canoe, ldf

Is it possible to use 2 LDF in the same CANoe configuration ?

Right now when I try to add the second LDF I get this error message:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience you can only use one ldf per LIN bus. If you have a second bus this one can have another ldf.

Maybe consider to combine the two ldf files into one before importing? The concept of lin with a single master controlling all the traffic should lead to no need of two different description files.

Comment: yes, this was also the awesore from Vector